# Sharepoint 2013 workflow to automatically trigger another workflow to start

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-manager

I have a workflow (1) that takes values from an infopath form and upates those values to a list called Employees. On the employees list I have another workflow (2) that is set to run when an item is created, or when an item is updated (I checked the start options). When workflow (1) updates items in the Employee Prospects list, workflow (2) is not starting. Is there any way I can setup workflow (1) to automatically trigger workflow (2)?

I am running a standard sharepoint license, and both workflows are created in SharePoint Designer 2013.

Answer (score 4):

You can't trigger 2nd workflow automatically (for now, maybe MS will solve recursion issue in the future), but there is a workaround to call it manually from 1st workflow described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2014/08/19/fix-sharepoint-2013-workflow-recursion-prevention-part-1.aspx

You need to have at least **May 2014 CU** for this to work.

I myself have implemented the fix for VS (step 3) and can confirm that it works. There is no reason why fix for SharePoint Designer (step 2) shouldn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

I had to replace my second workflow (2) with a 2010 workflow that starts when an item is created in the second list.  It all started working better after that.

Comment: This worked for me, too. But it is not ideal because the actions I want to perform on the item in the second list are *only* available to SPD2013 Workflows.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run the second workflow with elevated permission, to do this you will require to [add an App Step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/jj822159%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Even item created under the app step (making http post to create item to list B)is not innitiating the WF on List B.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old problem. To add this behaviour you need to install a Third party component to help you to call the another workflow, In the following link you can to download and install a Open Source Plugin to be able to start a workflow in another list using SharePoint Designer 2013.The solution Works in 2013 and 2016 SharePoint Versions with SharePoint 2013 workflows enabled.

The open source plugin you can download, executables or C# sources:
https://spworkflowstart.codeplex.com/

For more information about how to use it: https://irunsharepoint.wordpress.com/2017/01/03/irunsharepoint-workflow-starter/

Comment: if possible, try to explain or summarize the content of the link you provided. This is so that your answer provides helpful content even if the linked content ever goes away